# Is there an easier way to make a .csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib, seaborn

I am doing a project where I want to show how many times a certain dog breed was mentioned. There are three dog breeds (golden_retriever, labrador_retriever, chihuahua) and I already have all the numbers (266, 265, 179, respectively). I want to use seaborn (and matplotlib inline) to create a bar chart. So far, the only solution I’ve found is putting “golden_retriever” into a .csv file 266 times (and “labrador_retriever” 265 times, etc).

There is a more elegant solution, but I do not know it. Just to make it clear, I want each dog breed to have a space on the x-axis and each bar will have 266, 265, 179, respectively.
The code I have so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv(‘top_three_dogs.csv’)
sns.countplot(data = df, x = ‘breed_name’)
```

The .csv file looks like this, I just don’t want to have 710 rows when there is a better way to do it:

```
breed_name
golden_retriever
golden_retriever
golden_retriever
golden_retriever
labrador_retriever
labrador_retriever
chihuahua
chihuahua
```

The plot that comes from the sns.countplot code has 3 bars with golden_retriever with a count of 4 and labrador_retriever as well as chihuahua with a count of 2.

Comment: It would be far easier to list the dog once and have a column with how many times it appears.

Comment: I did try that, it was actually my first thought in trying to solve it. I just couldn’t get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `seaborn.countplot` function for this purpose, you may use an array instead of a `pandas.DataFrame` as the input data:

```
import seaborn as sns
dogs = ['golden_retriever'] * 266 + ['labrador_retriever'] * 265 + ['chihuahua'] * 179
sns.countplot(dogs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to avoid the multiple files, would be to first perform a value counts on the column of the data frame. This action will give you each dog breed and its frequency (number of times it appears on the column) then you can simply plot the seaborn plot. In this way, you can simply access the `breed_df` to see what you are plotting, and actually save this to a CSV file.
Result: Barplot with breed vs breed frecuency and `breeds_frecuency.csv` with the info!

```
df = pd.read_csv(‘top_three_dogs.csv’)
breed_df = df.breed.value_counts().sort_index().to_csv("breeds_frequency.csv")
seaborn.barplot(x=df.breed.value_counts().index,y=df.breed.value_counts())
```